# Integrability of a function on the unit ball and the complement of the unit ball

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Consider the function $f_a(x)=|x|^a$, $0\neq x \in \mathbb{R}^d$,$f_a(0)=0$,where $|x|$ denotes the Euclidean distance from $x$ to the origin in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a fixed parameter. For which values of $a$ is $f_a$ integrable on the unit ball $B=\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^d:|x| \leq 1 \}$. What about for integrability on $\mathbb{R}^d$\ $B$, for which values of $a$ is $f_a$ integrable?

Answer (score 3):

The volume element in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as
$$
d^{n}x=\left(r^{n-1}dr\right)\left(d^{n-1}\Omega\right),
$$
where $d^{n-1}\Omega$ is the area element on the surface of the $n$-sphere, and $\int d^{n-1}\Omega$ is the surface area of the unit $n$-sphere (e.g., $2\pi$ for $n=2$ and $4\pi/3$ for $n=3$).  So the integrability of $f(x)=|x|^{a}$ on the unit ball depends on whether $r^{a+n-1}$ is integrable at $r=0$; and its integrability on the complement of the unit ball depends on whether $r^{a+n-1}$ is integrable as $r\rightarrow\infty$.  In particular, the integral of $r^{a+n-1}$ is proportional to $r^{a+n}$ for $a\neq -n$, and to $\log r$ for $a=-n$, giving the following cases:

- $a<-n$: $\; f(x)$ integrable over $B^{c}$ but not $B$;
- $a=-n$: $\; f(x)$ not integrable over $B$ or $B^{c}$;
- $a>-n$: $\;f(x)$ integrable over $B$ but not $B^{c}$.